# How to make log in code in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hello Guys please help me about this code, 
This is simple log in code in visual studio 2013, my problem is, i try to make wrong password and user name, but the message box does not shows, it means no event after the "else"

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click

        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader


                Call OpenDB()
                Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM smcUser WHERE UserName = '" & txtTeacher.Text & "'AND UserPass ='" & txtPword.Text & "'")
                cmd.Connection = conn
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

                If dr.HasRows = True Then

                    dr.Read()
                    If dr.Item("UserName") = txtTeacher.Text And dr.Item("UserPass") = txtPword.Text Then

                        frmMain.Show()
                        Me.Hide()

                    Else

                        MsgBox("You are not a Registered Teacher")

                    End If
                End If


                dr.Close()

                frmMain.StatusStrip1.Items(0).Text = txtTeacher.Text
                Call CloseDB()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Never store passwords in plain text.

Comment: dr.HasRows will the *False* when the user gets it wrong.  Which of course in your code also bypasses the MsgBox() call.  Simple bug.  You shot your foot by thinking that you have to check the user+pass *again*.  You don't, your query already did that.  Improve your code and heal your foot by properly reporting an unknown user name vs a bad password.

Comment: SQL injection alert!

Comment: `dr.HasRows` will be `False` if the SQL query do not meet the where condition.

Comment: Never right your own authentication code. It's too easy to build something the _seems_ to work, but is still flawed in such a way that you find yourself hacked six months later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your query `"SELECT * FROM smcUser WHERE UserName = '" & txtTeacher.Text & "'AND UserPass ='" & txtPword.Text & "'"` does not return anything when you enter the wrong password, so it never even executes the code within the `If dr.HasRows = True Then` block.

Also, you should **NEVER** store passwords in plain text.  Hash them.  And, you should always use parameters to preclude SQL injection attacks.

So, you would want to change your code to something like this:

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM smcUser WHERE UserName = @UserName  AND UserPass = @HashedPassword")
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@UserName", txtTeacher.Txt))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@HashedPassword", HasherFunction(txtPword.Txt)))
```

Note the addition of the parameters and also the `HasherFunction` which you would have to build to hash your password accordingly.

There are plenty of resources available about SQL injection and how to avoid it.  Here's one I found at the top of the Google search: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score -1):

you almost there in your code, just don't repeat the checking if the user exists in the database, and you code should be like this based on what you put in the question

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
                Call OpenDB()
                Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM smcUser WHERE UserName = '" & txtTeacher.Text & "'AND UserPass ='" & txtPword.Text & "'")
                cmd.Connection = conn
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

                If dr.HasRows = True Then
                ' you don't need to check again if the user and password are same since you made it
                ' in you query to database
                     frmMain.Show()
                     Me.Hide()
                Else
                        MsgBox("You are not a Registered Teacher")
               End If


                dr.Close()

                frmMain.StatusStrip1.Items(0).Text = txtTeacher.Text
                Call CloseDB()

    End Sub
```

hope it will help you